# What is the relationship between Asynchronous Module Definition and Progressive Web Apps?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, amd

When I search for the combination of Asynchronous Module Definition and Progressive Web Apps, not much comes up. I can imagine however that PWA's would benefit from AMD. Hence my question.

Comment: nothing. AMD is a JavaScript concept
PWA are websites that leverage modern web APIs and good user experience practices to delivery a great, app-like, UX.

Comment: don't websites generally use JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, but that does not make them progressive web applications. You can be a PWA without any UI JavaScript or using AMD. 
Think about it this way, the concepts are decoupled from each other.